# Android: Out of memory on a 150994960-byte allocation

Tags: java, android, memory

If I use a genymotion emulator it works well, but if i'm testing it on my phone it won't respond.
I realy don't know why, but if I do set ContentView. I get the following error:

> 03-18 12:09:39.291 17403-17403/com.a42.tell I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap
>   (frag case) to 115.420MB for 7817488-byte allocation 03-18
>   12:09:47.416 17403-17403/com.a42.tell I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing
>   collection of SoftReferences for 150994960-byte allocation 03-18
>   12:09:47.436 17403-17403/com.a42.tell E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory
>   on a 150994960-byte allocation.

can somebody tell me where the problem is or where i need to look to fix this error!

```
public class FriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //System.gc();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends); // It breaks here 
    ...
    }
}
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_contacts"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvContacts"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

UPDATE1: This is the adapter

```
public class FriendsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private RealmResults<UserRealm> mDataset;
    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView tv_name;
        public long idto; //TODO: Do i still need this ?
        public ImageView micBtn;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tv_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            micBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.mic);




        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public FriendsAdapter(RealmResults<UserRealm> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                         int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.friends_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        vh.micBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL){Log.d("tagger", "ACTION_CANCEL"); return true;}

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){Log.d("tagger", "ACTION_DOWN"); return true;}

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){Log.d("tagger", "ACTION_MOVE"); return true;}

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){Log.d("tagger", "ACTION_UP"); return true;}
                return false;
            }
        });




        return vh;
    }


    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(mDataset.get(position).getFullname());
                      holder.idto = 1;



    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }
}
```

Update2: the entire stack trace

> 03-18 13:36:09.450 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced
>   from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
>   03-18 13:36:09.450 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable
>   to resolve virtual method 222:
>   Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly
>   (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder; 03-18 13:36:09.455
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from
>   method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh 03-18
>   13:36:09.455 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 499:
>   Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller
>   ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller; 03-18 13:36:09.490
>   27910-27935/com.a42.jutella I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
>   03-18 13:36:09.535 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
>   03-18 13:36:09.535 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable
>   to resolve virtual method 575:
>   Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-18
>   13:36:09.535 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not find
>   method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-18
>   13:36:09.535 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 597: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType
>   (I)I 03-18 13:36:09.755 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm-heap:
>   Grow heap (frag case) to 105.720MB for 81432016-byte allocation 03-18
>   13:36:10.120 27910-27957/com.a42.jutella I/tagger: GCM Registration
>   Token:
>   eBVKL3ktgP8:APA91bFhgmYCHFaE3Vg7lVmnGusIsQd3XSOQeSV8XFgVY9pVHm_6CIHf5MCbX4DG3o65epGMFvAmeHhAIOuYD8UK170VSPj17ECmLyBfcF-3RnnIeEO2NRzKrlDneeJeYfOr6gV69g-J
>   03-18 13:36:11.985 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from
>   method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
>   03-18 13:36:11.985 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable
>   to resolve virtual method 538:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable
>   (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   03-18 13:36:11.985 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Could not
>   find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity,
>   referenced from method
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
>   03-18 13:36:11.985 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable
>   to resolve virtual method 540:
>   Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity
>   (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
>   03-18 13:36:14.390 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow
>   heap (frag case) to 115.151MB for 7817488-byte allocation 03-18
>   13:36:14.410 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$4', referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.getObjectObservable 03-18
>   13:36:14.410 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve new-instance 4347 (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory; 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$3', referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.getRealmResultsObservable 03-18
>   13:36:14.410 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve new-instance 4344 (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory; 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$2', referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.from 03-18 13:36:14.410
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 4341 (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory; 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory$1', referenced from method
>   io.realm.rx.RealmObservableFactory.from 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 4338 (Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;) in
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory; 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lrx/Observable;) 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$4;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$3;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$2;' failed 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: Failed resolving
>   Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1; interface 4910
>   'Lrx/Observable$OnSubscribe;' 03-18 13:36:14.415
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: Link of class
>   'Lio/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory$1;' failed 03-18 13:36:16.035
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of
>   SoftReferences for 150994960-byte allocation 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a
>   150994960-byte allocation. 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:   |
>   group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x417bed50 self=0x417ad668 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=27910
>   nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074200916 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=(
>   2243809464 48789052 1220 ) utm=165 stm=58 core=5 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:606)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:433)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2168) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   com.huawei.android.content.res.ResourcesEx.loadDrawable(ResourcesEx.java:649)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:650) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3562) 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:470) 03-18 13:36:16.055
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:166)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:162)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
>   03-18 13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:409) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:358) 03-18
>   13:36:16.055 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   com.a42.jutella.FriendsActivity.onCreate(FriendsActivity.java:27)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5285) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 03-18 13:36:16.060
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5314) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 03-18 13:36:16.060
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   03-18 13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:678) 03-18
>   13:36:16.060 27910-27910/com.a42.jutella I/dalvikvm:     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-18 13:36:16.065
>   27910-27910/com.a42.jutella W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x417bdc50)

Comment: Are you by any chance loading any `Bitmap`s? Images? Into `ImageView`s?

Comment: No, i'm aware loading a bitmap can cause problems. I have deleted all images. so i'm sure that's not the problem. I am using realm for local storage.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If you don't have any `android:background` set to a drawable, and you're not showing images, then you'll have to show your adapter code. I'm curious about your Realm access.

Comment: Please post **the entire stack trace**, not just a couple of oddly-formatted lines.